# Не работает React-https-redirect в chrome. Можно ли как-то ускорить работу редиректа?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, http-redirect

Начал искать информацию о том как сделать http-https редирект в react app. Наткнулся на информацию что нужно использовать библиотеку React-https-redirect. Обернул App, в firefox все работает (хотя думает очень долго), в chrome тишина. В целом хорошая практика юзать эту библиотеку? Какие есть варианты?

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Для каких целей используете эту библиотеку?

Comment: Редирект с http на https